# How to pass any Class that implements a particular interface as a parameter and use its methods?

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparator

I created my own "LinkedList" class that can take in objects specified with a generic.

In that Class, I want to have a **sort(ComparatorObject)** method that takes in an object whose Class implements Comparator.

The reason for that is that for my test objects in particular, Shapes, I want to see if I can sort them by various fields selected by the user, such as the shapes' areas, perimeter, type, etc.

Right now, one of my comparator classes is defined like this:

```
public class Comparator_Area implements Comparator<Shape>{

@Override
public int compare(Shape shape1, Shape shape2) {
    int valueToReturn = 0;

    if(shape1.getArea() < shape2.getArea()){
        valueToReturn = -1;
    }
    else if(shape1.getArea() < shape2.getArea()){
        valueToReturn = 1;
    }

    return valueToReturn;
}
}
```

And in my LinkedList Class, my sort method is defined like this (I don't know if it's correct, but it's what I found while looking up how to do this):

```
public void sort(Class<? extends Comparator<E>> comparator){

}
```

Naturally, I'd like to be able to use something like this in the sort method:

```
comparator.compare(shape1, shape2);
```

But I can't use "compare" and I don't really know how I'm supposed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send a `Comparator` object as parameter in your sort method:

```
public void sort(Comparator<Shape> comparator){

}
```

This is assuming your LinkedList class is only of `Shape`s. If you have a generic LinkedList implementation, then you can pass a `Comparator<T>`:

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> {
    //other methods...

    public void sort(Comparator<T> comparator){

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think I could do this since Comparator is an Interface. It works now! And @ignis what is the difference between what you posted and what is in the answer? Does your way mean that the compared object can only be a child of T?

Comment: If Shape extends Drawable, a Comparator<Drawable> is a Comparator<? super Shape>, but not a Comparator<Shape>. So you cannot pass a Comparator<Drawable> if the parameter type is Comparator<Shape>.

Comment: Oh - and a Comparator<Shape> is always a Comparator<? super Shape>.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `Class` object as parameter. Try the following instead:

```
public void sort(Comparator<T> comparator){

}
```

where `T` is the generic type of your `LinkedList`.

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be this simple. I thought since it was an Interface I couldn't do this. Thanks a lot, it works now!